# Trying to run a Node app from sub-directory in App Service serves server.js file

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I have a strange issue trying to run a Node app in a sub-directory on an Azure App Service.

My directory structure is:

```
|common
  -- common_model.js
|client
  -- angular 2 app js files
|server
  -- server.js with other express app files
|web.config
```

I've configured the web.config file to point all requests to the server\server.js file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="server\server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="server\server.js"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
        <remove segment="bin"/>
        <add segment="node_modules" />
        </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When loading up the site in a browser, the content of server.js is returned and is not executed. What else might I need other than the iisnode handler configured to make this run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite setting the path:

`<add name="iisnode" path="server\server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>`

The iisnode module seem to only function with the server.js file in the root. The solution is luckily simple enough, just create a server.js file in the root that simply includes the sub-directory file. The whole file is one line:

`require("./server/server.js");`

Then you can use the default iisnode handler:

`<add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>`

Comment: really helpful. saved a lot of time